# Язык си робота с массивами

Tags: c, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Написать программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры массив из 6 целых чисел и
изменяет его следующим образом: первый элемент меняется местами с последним, второй –
с предпоследним и.т.д.
При вводе с клавиатуры 15 целых чисел они выводятся в той же последовательности в которой вводились без изменений. Как изменить код программы чтобы условия соблюдалось.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 6

int main()
{
 int ARR[N];
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<N;++i)
 scanf("%d",&ARR[i]);
 for (i=0;i<N;++i)
 printf(" %d ",ARR[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код от новичка в Си :)

```
    int n;
    printf("Введите длинну массива :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int A[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Введите значение для A[%i] :", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        int tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[n - i - 1];
        A[n - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
```

```
printf("Введите элементы массива через пробел :\n");
    
    int count = 0;
    int A[100000];
 
    do {
        scanf("%d", &A[count++]);
    } while (getchar() != '\n' && count < 100);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++) {
        int tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[count - i - 1];
        A[count - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!! А можно сделать так чтобы программа работала без видения длины массива. Например вводим с клавиатуры: 12 45 77 38 66 22 а выводится 22 66 38 77 45 12.

Comment: @Александр я изменил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Хочу поблагодарить еще раз за помощь я немного переделал твой код мой вариант выглядит таким образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 6

int main()
{
  int A[n];
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}
  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
{
  int tmp = A[i];
  A[i]=A[n-i-1];
  A[n-i-1]=tmp;
}
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  printf(" %d ",A[i]);
}
}
```